# Read excel application status bar text

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, vba

Is there any way to get excel application status bar text?

[image]

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: which langauage did you actually want to ask this in?

Comment: VSTO Project of visual studio. Language c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm definitly not sure but you can try like this;

[`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms282265%28v=office.14%29.aspx) interface has [`StatusBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.statusbar%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property.

> Returns or sets the text in the status bar.
>
> This property returns False if Microsoft Excel has control of the
>   status bar. To restore the default status bar text, set the property
>   to False; this works even if the status bar is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.LogAction "New Status"
```

or

```
LOG_Handler.LogAction "New Status"
```